# Can a FSBL load another FSBL?

Tags: assembly, bootloader

I am currently exploring the bootloader world.

However I asked myself if it is possible for a first stage bootloader to load and run another first stage bootloader. (lets say it lays on a FAT partition)

If so what would be the preferred way?
If not why?

Comment: Yes, of course, why not. See also chainloading.

Answer (score 3):

Just be sure to:

1. Load the new FSBL in the proper segment.
   This usually means `0000:7c00` that in turns imply that you have to overwrite your current bootloader.
   You can relocate a routine (that you cared to make position independent) that could be as simple as setting `ds:si`, `es:di` and `cx` for a (slow) `rep movsb/w/d`.
2. Set the registers properly.
   The BIOS hands control to the FSBL with definite register values (see section 6.5.1 of [the relative specifications](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/05au-cs240c/lab/specsbbs101.pdf)), you have to save those values (even to fixed memory locations) and restore them.

Some bootloaders could be [additional constrains](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/DOS_002fWindows.html#DOS_002fWindows) for a successful chainload.